# Gridview presentation of date different than query in one cell

Tags: c#, asp.net

My gridview is showing a date differently than the query that it uses does:

[image]

[image]

All of the dates are of the convention I decided on in the query. But the first date (Monday) is the wrong ocnvention on the gridview. I don't see any reason why this would be.

Here is the Gridview (The query it uses is very long):

```
        <asp:GridView CssClass="hoursGrid" ID="hoursReportGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="#DEBA84" BorderColor="#DEBA84" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="2" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" OnRowDataBound="hoursReportGridView_OnRowDataBound">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Person" HeaderText="Person" SortExpression="Project" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Project" HeaderText="Project" SortExpression="Project" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Sprint" HeaderText="Sprint" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Sprint" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Story" HeaderText="Story" SortExpression="Story" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Task" HeaderText="Task" SortExpression="Task" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Monday" HeaderText="Monday" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Monday" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Tuesday" HeaderText="Tuesday" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Tuesday" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Wednesday" HeaderText="Wednesday" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Wednesday" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Thursday" HeaderText="Thursday" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Thursday" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Friday" HeaderText="Friday" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Friday" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Saturday" HeaderText="Saturday" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Saturday" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Sunday" HeaderText="Sunday" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Sunday" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Total" HeaderText="Total" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Total" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#F7DFB5" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#A55129" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#FFF7E7" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFF1D4" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#B95C30" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1E5CE" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#93451F" />
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>" SelectCommand="
     SELECT RowType AS RowType
    ,Person AS Person
    ,Project AS Project
    ,Sprint AS Sprint
    ,Story AS Story
    ,Task AS Task
    ,MondayHours AS Monday
    ,TuesdayHours AS Tuesday
    ,WednesdayHours AS Wednesday
    ,ThursdayHours AS Thursday
    ,FridayHours AS Friday
    ,SaturdayHours AS Saturday
    ,SundayHours AS Sunday
    ,TotalHours AS Total
FROM (
    SELECT '1' AS RowType
        ,'' AS Person
        ,'' AS Project
        ,'' AS Sprint
        ,'' AS Story
        ,'' AS Task
        ,(
            CASE 
                WHEN DATEPART(dw, @startDateParam) = 2
                    THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @startDateParam, 111)
                ELSE ''
                END
            ) AS MondayHours
        ,(
            CASE 
                WHEN DATEPART(dw, DATEADD(DAY, 1, @startDateParam)) = 3
                    THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY, 1, @startDateParam), 111)
                ELSE ''
                END
            ) AS TuesdayHours
        ,(
            CASE 
                WHEN DATEPART(dw, DATEADD(DAY, 2, @startDateParam)) = 4
                    THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY, 2, @startDateParam), 111)
                ELSE ''
                END
            ) AS WednesdayHours
        ,(
            CASE 
                WHEN DATEPART(dw, DATEADD(DAY, 3, @startDateParam)) = 5
                    THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY, 3, @startDateParam), 111)
                ELSE ''
                END
            ) AS ThursdayHours
        ,(
            CASE 
                WHEN DATEPART(dw, DATEADD(DAY, 4, @startDateParam)) = 6
                    THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY, 4, @startDateParam), 111)
                ELSE ''
                END
            ) AS FridayHours
        ,(
            CASE 
                WHEN DATEPART(dw, DATEADD(DAY, 5, @startDateParam)) = 7
                    THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY, 5, @startDateParam), 111)
                ELSE ''
                END
            ) AS SaturdayHours
        ,(
            CASE 
                WHEN DATEPART(dw, DATEADD(DAY, 6, @startDateParam)) = 1
                    THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY, 6, @startDateParam), 111)
                ELSE ''
                END
            ) AS SundayHours
        ,'' AS TotalHours
    --

    UNION ALL

    --
    SELECT '4' AS RowType
        ,DTH.PointPerson AS Person
        ,PDT.[Name] AS Project
        ,(
            CASE 
                WHEN TSK.NAME IS NULL
                    THEN NULL
                WHEN SPT.[Name] + ' - ' + SPT.[Description] IS NULL
                    THEN 'KanBan'
                ELSE SPT.[Name] + ' - ' + SPT.[Description]
                END
            ) AS Sprint
        ,COALESCE(STY.[Number], NSS.IncidentNumber) AS Story
        ,TSK.[Name] AS Task
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 2
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS MondayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 3
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS TuesdayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 4
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS WednesdayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 5
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS ThursdayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 6
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS FridayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 7
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS SaturdayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 1
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS SundayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(DTH.[Hours]) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS TotalHours
    FROM DailyTaskHours DTH
    LEFT JOIN Task TSK ON DTH.TaskId = TSK.PK_Task
    LEFT JOIN Story STY ON TSK.StoryId = STY.PK_Story
    LEFT JOIN NonScrumStory NSS ON DTH.NonScrumStoryId = NSS.PK_NonScrumStory
    LEFT JOIN Sprint SPT ON STY.SprintId = SPT.PK_Sprint
    LEFT JOIN Product PDT ON STY.ProductId = PDT.PK_Product
     WHERE DTH.PointPerson LIKE @userParam 
     AND ActivityDate &gt;= @startDateParam 
     AND ActivityDate &lt;= @endDateParam
    GROUP BY DTH.PointPerson
        ,PDT.[Name]
        ,SPT.[Name]
        ,SPT.[Description]
        ,STY.[Number]
        ,NSS.IncidentNumber
        ,TSK.[Name]
    HAVING SUM(DTH.[Hours]) > 0
    --

    UNION ALL

    --
    SELECT '3' AS RowType
        ,DTH.PointPerson AS Person
        ,'' AS Project
        ,'' AS Sprint
        ,'' AS Story
        ,'' AS Task
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 2
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS MondayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 3
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS TuesdayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 4
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS WednesdayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 5
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS ThursdayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 6
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS FridayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 7
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS SaturdayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 1
                        THEN DTH.[Hours]
                    ELSE 0
                    END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS SundayHours
        ,CAST(SUM(DTH.[Hours]) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS TotalHours
    FROM DailyTaskHours DTH
    LEFT JOIN Task TSK ON DTH.TaskId = TSK.PK_Task
    LEFT JOIN Story STY ON TSK.StoryId = STY.PK_Story
    LEFT JOIN NonScrumStory NSS ON DTH.NonScrumStoryId = NSS.PK_NonScrumStory
    LEFT JOIN Sprint SPT ON STY.SprintId = SPT.PK_Sprint
    LEFT JOIN Product PDT ON STY.ProductId = PDT.PK_Product
     WHERE DTH.PointPerson LIKE @userParam 
     AND ActivityDate &gt;= @startDateParam 
     AND ActivityDate &lt;= @endDateParam
    GROUP BY DTH.PointPerson
    HAVING SUM(DTH.[Hours]) > 0
    ) AS My_View
--
UNION ALL
--
SELECT '2' AS RowType
    ,'All Personnel' AS Person
    ,'' AS Project
    ,'' AS Sprint
    ,'' AS Story
    ,'' AS Task
    ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 2
                    THEN DTH.[Hours]
                ELSE 0
                END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS Monday
    ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 3
                    THEN DTH.[Hours]
                ELSE 0
                END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS Tuesday
    ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 4
                    THEN DTH.[Hours]
                ELSE 0
                END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS Wednesday
    ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 5
                    THEN DTH.[Hours]
                ELSE 0
                END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS Thursday
    ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 6
                    THEN DTH.[Hours]
                ELSE 0
                END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS Friday
    ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 7
                    THEN DTH.[Hours]
                ELSE 0
                END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS Saturday
    ,CAST(SUM(CASE 
                WHEN DATEPART(dw, DTH.ActivityDate) = 1
                    THEN DTH.[Hours]
                ELSE 0
                END) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS Sunday
    ,CAST(SUM(DTH.[Hours]) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS Total
FROM DailyTaskHours DTH
     WHERE ActivityDate &gt;= @startDateParam 
     AND ActivityDate &lt;= @endDateParam
ORDER BY RowType
    ,Person
    ,Project
    ,Sprint
    ,Story
    ,Task">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="userParam" Type="String" DefaultValue="%" />
                <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="startDateParam" Type="String" />
                <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="endDateParam" Type="String" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking that because you use DATEADD in all other days, it somehow transforms the result.

Try using

```
DATEADD(DAY, 0, @startDateParam)
```

for MondayHours, and see if the results are consistent for all days.

Comment: That was it, can't believe I missed it. Thanks!